# XSLT code - retrieving data from xml(substring)

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following string as a text node in an XML document:

```
OK - load average: 0.34,0.02,0.34
USERS OK - 0 users currently logged in,100,200
HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
PING OK - Packet loss = 0%
DISK OK - free space: / 34285 MB (82% inode=94%):
```

From the above string i would like to have the xslt code for getting only the first numeric data, for example expected output as below:

```
0.34
100
null or blank
null or blank
null or blank
```

As the above validation is done retrieved after : or ,

I am new to XSLT and seems to bit complicated to get this data, as validation seems to be different for each case.

I appreciate anybody's help on it...

Comment: Do you have an example of the xml data you will be translating with the XSLT?

Comment: Are you sure that's the input format? That's not XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure your string will be something like your example every time you can do something like this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(mystringvalue,': '),',')"/>
```

For a good source for XSLT functions checkout [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="vLines" select="tokenize(., '\n\r?')"/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$vLines">
   <xsl:value-of select=
   "if(matches(.,':\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?)'))
      then
        (replace(., '^.*?:\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?).*$','$1'),'&#xA;')
      else
       if(matches(.,',\s*\d+(\.\d+)?'))
         then
          (replace(., '^.*?,\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?).*$','$1'),'&#xA;')
       else
         'null&#xA;'

       "/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>OK - load average: 0.34,0.02,0.34
USERS OK - 0 users currently logged in,100,200
HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
PING OK - Packet loss = 0%
DISK OK - free space: / 34285 MB (82% inode=94%):</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
0.34 
100 
null
null
null
```

---

**A single XPath 2.0 expression solution:**

```
for $vLine in
 ('OK - load average: 0.34,0.02,0.34'
 , 'USERS OK - 0 users currently logged in,100,200'
 ,'HTTP WARNING: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'
 , 'PING OK - Packet loss = 0%'
 , 'DISK OK - free space: / 34285 MB (82% inode=94%):'
 )

return
  if(matches($vLine,':\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?)'))
   then
    (replace($vLine, '^.*?:\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?).*$','$1'),'&#xA;')
  else
   if(matches($vLine,',\s*\d+(\.\d+)?'))
     then
      (replace($vLine, '^.*?,\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?).*$','$1'),'&#xA;')
   else
     'null&#xA;'
```